# using stats[importdata]( ) to import file

Tags: maple

I want to import a file using statsimportdata and do an histogram but when i do:

```
with(stats);
newdata:=importdata("data1.dat"):
histogram(newdata)
```

it gives me an :Error, (in stats/statplots/functions/histogram) bad argument to histogram 95.0
I think the problem is that it saves a data into a sequence not into a list, but I am required to use the import data. Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quickly turn an expression sequence into a list by wrapping it in square brackets.

For example,

```
newdata := [ importdata("data1.dat") ]:
```

Judging solely from the error message you've cited, it does look as if your problem is that you were passing a sequence rather than a list.

By the way, the command `Statistics:-Histogram` can handle large amounts of data much faster than can the command `stats[statplots,histogram]`. The former has been available for several years (several major releases of Maple), and is generally more powerful.